# My python is calling another function from another file without explicitly importing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces

I had developed 2 python (3.x) scripts.  They each followed some basic flow in the body by calling these methods
- `process_params()`
- `run(params)`

I now have a use case where it is useful for my first python script to call a specific function in my second python script.

So, to prevent name conflicts of `process_params()` and `run(params)`, I did the following:
- Put both files in the same directory.
- In my first python script, I have essentially following:

```
sys.path.append(".")
from script2 import needed_function
```

To my horror and surprise, when I called "script1", it is invoking script2's `process_params()` even though I didn't import it!!!

I then attempted to create a small-simple test case to demonstrate this unexpected behavior.  However, I failed; the test case return what I expected by using the local `process_params()`!

That means that there is something really odd (something that I messed up) in my actual code where script1 will call script2's `process_params()` instead of its own local instance when I had only import a single and different method from script2.  Since the problem is probably "unique" to how my actual scripts' code is; but the scripts are long and it has confidential information as well that I cannot post them here.  Are there suggestions or theories that anyone can suggest on how I approach this problem?

Comment: You probably have the function being called in script2.

Comment: Are you relying on module-level variables inside your `needed_function`?

Comment: You don't have to disclose private code or data to post a good question. Actually, you're even encouraged to strip all that's irrelevant by making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here. You might also have a look at [“what does `if __name__ == "__main__"` do?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), which could by your issue.

Comment: When you import a module, ALL of it gets executed even if you are importing only one thing from it. Use an `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard to make module-level statements execute only that file is called as the "main" script.

Comment: Thank you all....  Yes, I totally forgot about using the if __name__ == "__main__"; this makes sense.  This is so obvious now.  Damn.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely calling `process_params` from the module level.

The following shows the behavior you are describing

s1.py

```
from s2 import needed_function
def foo():
    print("Script 1 foo() called")


foo()
needed_function()
```

s2.py

```
def needed_function():
    print("needed_function called")

def foo():
    print("Script 2 foo() called")

foo()
```

Which, when I run s1.py, prints the following

```
$ python s1.py 
Script 2 foo() called
Script 1 foo() called
needed_function called
```

You need to check for `__name__ == "__main__"` to guard your calls. Whenever the module is imported, `__name__` will contain the module name. Only when it's the module that is run directly will it be `__main__`.

So, slight modifications give

```
# s3.py
from s4 import needed_function
def foo():
    print("Script 3 foo() called")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
    needed_function()from s4 import needed_function
def foo():
    print("Script 3 foo() called")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
    needed_function()

# s4.py
def needed_function():
    print("needed_function called")

def foo():
    print("Script 4 foo() called")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```

and, likely, the desired results

```
$ python s3.py 
Script 3 foo() called
needed_function called
```

Comment: Thanks so much for such detail response with a clear approach!